# Is the quotient of a projective manifold still a projective manifold?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, projective-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Let $X$ be a complex projective manifold and $G$ a finite group acting on $X$, then is the quotient manifold $Y=X/G$ still a projective manifold?

This question comes from a paper of Cao Junyan[《On the approximation of Kähler manifolds by algebraic varieties》](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00208-014-1097-4)p403-p404, which talk about the finite covering $\hat X$ of $X$, I will explain it as follows:

Let $X$ be a compact Kähler manifold with Hermitian semipositive anticanonical bundle, by the structure theorem (cf[DPS96]), the universal cover $\tilde X$ can be splited as $\tilde X=\mathbb C^q\times Y\times P$, $Y$ denotes a product of Calabi-Yau manifolds and $P$ denotes a projective manifold, and there exist a normal subgroup $\Gamma$ of $\pi_1(X)$ such that $G=\pi_1(X)/\Gamma$ is a finite group, let $\hat X=\tilde X/\Gamma$, obviously we have $X=\hat X/G$, then there exist a smooth fibration $\pi:\hat X\rightarrow F$ where $F:=(\mathbb C^q\times Y)/\Gamma$ is a Ricci-flat compact manifold. I know we can always deform a Ricci-flat manifold to a projective manifold, so a projective deformation of $F$ may induce a projective deformation of $\hat X$, if the quotient map of $G$ may keep the projectivity, it may also induce a projective deformation of $X$ which is exactly what I need, so my question is:

Is the quotient of $\hat X$ by a finite group $G$ acting on $\hat X$ still  projective?

Can anyone help me to figure out whether it is true? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The quotient won't even be a manifold if $G$ doesn't act freely; take, for example, a rotation of order $3$ acting on $\mathbb{CP}^1$. But if you start with $X$ and take a finite Galois cover $\hat{X}$ then freeness is automatic. It's hard to say more without knowing more about how this paper constructs $X$ and $\hat{X}$ and what you do or don't know about them.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan ,thanks for your valuable comments, I have added more information to the question, is it clear now? And do you know this statement is true of false?

Comment: You're asking for something more general than you need (which is false); $G$ is not acting arbitrarily on $\hat{X}$, it's a covering space action, so in particular free. But I don't know enough about complex geometry to tell you if this is enough.

Comment: If a finite group $G$ acts freely on a quasi-projective variety over a field of char zero, then the quotient $X/G$ is again quasi-projective. References can be found on MathOverflow...See here for example : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/70018/quotient-of-a-variety-by-a-finite-group-scheme?rq=1 Actually, freeness of the action is not even necessary.

Comment: Maybe I should also add that, if a finite group G acts freely on a variety X, then X/G is smooth if and only if X is smooth.

Comment: @Ariyan Javanpeykar, I'm not familiar with the language of algebraic geometry, for example quasi-projective, in particular for my question, does it mean if $\hat X$ is a projective manifold, then the quotient $X$ is also projective?

Comment: Yes, it does. There exist more analytical arguments, if you prefer. I cannot post this as an answer right now, since I don't have the time to look up references, but the properties of being Kähler and Moishezon descend onto the (smooth, finite) quotient, so the quotient is projective as well.

Comment: @Ben, thanks, the information you provide is very helpful, and if you can provide some reference, it will be more helpful to us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There has been an answer in the comments, but the OP seems to prefer a more analytical language. Here is the canonical textbook reference:

As was noticed in the comments, in the given situation, the quotient map $f\colon \hat X\to X$ is a finite unramified cover. Thus, a corollary of the Kodaira Embedding Theorem in Griffiths and Harris' *Principles of Algebraic Geometry*, p. 192, applies. It states that for such a finite unramified cover, the base is projective if and only if so is the covering space.

The proof of the implication we need more or less goes like this. By the Kodaira Embedding Theorem, it is sufficient that there be a closed, positive $(1,1)$-form whose cohomology class is rational. If $\hat X$ is projective, then there exists such a $(1,1)$-form $\omega$ on $\hat X$. Since $f$ is a finite unbranched cover, a suitable coordinate chart $U$ around $p\in X$ is covered by a bunch of charts $\coprod_{i=1}^n V_i=f^{-1}U$ and a $(1,1)$-form $\omega'$ is defined as the trace: $\omega'|_U=\sum_{i=1}^n \omega|_{V_i}$ (through obvious identifications). The proof is concluded by the observation that this defines a closed, positive $(1,1)$-form on $X$ whose cohomology class is rational.

Comment: Alternatively, you can find a finite cover $\hat{X}' \to \hat{X}$ such that the finite cover $\hat{X}' \to X$ is a normal covering. As $\hat{X}$ is projective, so is $\hat{X}'$. If $\omega$ is a closed positive $(1, 1)$-form whose cohomology class is rational, then averaging over the deck transformations of $\hat{X}' \to X$, one obtains an invariant such form, so it descends to a closed positive $(1, 1)$-form on $X$ whose cohomology class is rational.